# Can virtualenv include necessary project packages from site-packages

Tags: python, virtualenv

Running command line:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

I'm expecting venv folder `venv\Lib\site-packages` to contain all the necessary library from the projects that are located in:
`C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\`

But it's not the case, only a few are installed.

Example, my program currently use `pdfminer` which is in

`C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\`

I want it to be included in `venv\Lib\site-packages` but it is not copied.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--system-site-packages` doesn't copy packages, it just allows python from the virtualenv to access packages in `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\`.

There is no way to copy packages because they could depend on their installation directory. If you want these packages in the virtualenv don't use `--system-site-packages` and install all packages in the virtualenv.

Comment: Hi,
Many thanks for your feedback. I'm not sure to understand the goal of a virtual env if  when creating it, there is no command line that can install the packages necessary for the project. 

We can read on https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ that "virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments. virtualenv creates a folder which contains all the necessary executables to use the packages that a Python project would need. " 
But if my env depend of external libraries then the use is limited. 
What's your view on that? Any command I'm missing to do so?

Comment: If you have many virtual environments they may depend on external libraries, but every single venv is isolated from each other. You can have a venv with library `xxx` version 1 that depends on `yyy` version 2 and you can have a venv with library `xxx` version 2 that depends on `yyy` version 3, for example.

Comment: How do I "install all packages in the virtualenv"? Not with virtualenv command? You mean I just pip install in my virtualenv or I just copy past the packages in my project "venv\Lib\site-packages"?

Comment: See my answer, which addresses your last question.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. After doing again a virtual env on another machine I could get the result expected. I needed to activate first the virtual env before i could install the requirements. When I did so it install all the lib at the right place

Answer (score 0):

A virtualenv environment is the same as if you have just installed a new version of Python.  It has no packages other than the standard packages provided with Python.  If you want other packages, you have to install them with 'pip' or however you'd do it with the native Python version that you are using.

So in general, just do `pip install <packagename>`.

If you find yourself often wanting to create virtualenvs with a standard set of base packages, then put together a requirements.txt file listing all of the packages you want to install as a base, and do `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside a new virtualenv, right after you create it.

One nice thing about a virtualenv is that it's all yours.  Your user owns 100% of it, unlike the base Python version that is owned by the system.  To install new packages into the base Python version, you often have to have root access (sudo privileges).  With virtualenvs, you don't need special permissions (in fact, you'll get all screwed up if you use `sudo` in a virtualenv) to install all the packages you want.  Everything you do lives within your own home directory.  Another neat thing is that when you are done with a virtualenv, you just throw away the root directory that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

If its not mandatory to use virtualenv, I would suggest to go with Anaconda. That'll pretty much help your concern.

Conda as a package manager helps you find and install packages. By default quite a few packages are already installed, so as to set you up quickly for your project. To check the list of packages installed in terminal, type: conda list to obtain the packages installed using conda.

If you need a package that requires a different version of Python, you do not need to switch to a different environment manager, because conda is also an environment manager.

With just a few commands, you can set up a totally separate environment to run that different version of Python, while continuing to run your usual version of Python in your normal environment

Comment: Thanks. Issue was not to find the packages I needed to install properly them in my virtual environment by using "requirements.txt". I somehow couldn't do it on one machine. Packages were appearing in my C drive with python and not with my project. But once I reinstall python on another machine and activate the virtual environment properly I was able to install the packages within that environment.